# Exporting MySql DB

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am using Mysql database for my Java project. I have created DB connection using following command:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
```

Now I am exporting `MySql` DB on other PC by creating `MySqlDump` file so that my project can run on other PC. I have created same database on other pc. But for running my project on other pc, I have to change password which I have set in my project with host machine password. Problem is that after making Jar file of project, how I would be able to do so. If I don't give user name and password in `getConnection()` method, data is not loaded into `JTable` in my project. What to do?